# How to use libcloud library in python

Tags: python, api, interface, libcloud, apiclient

I am trying to to list images in CloudStack, using libcloud api in Python:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider 
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver 
from libcloud.common.base import Response 
#import libcloud.security as sec 
#sec.VERIFY_SSL_CERT = False 
#USER = 'ACCESSKEY' 
#API_KEY = 'SECRETKEY' 
Driver = get_driver(Provider.CLOUDSTACK) 
url = 'MY URL' 
conn = Driver(key=USER, secret=API_KEY, url=url) 
print "Connection established" 
images = conn.list_images() 
print images
```

When running this code, I get the following error:

```
 body = self.parse_body()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 195,
 in parse_body driver=self.connection.driver) 
 libcloud.common.types.MalformedResponseError: <MalformedResponseException in
 <libcloud.compute.drivers.cloudstack.CloudStackNodeDriver object at 0x7fc356f55b50>
 'Failed to parse JSON'>: 'Unknown_ApiKey'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Hi all,   I ve execute above code,i got output like this:{'secure': True, 'connection': <libcloud.common.cloudstack.CloudStackConnection object at 0x7fca78dbf3d0>, 'region': None, 'secret': 'mysecretkey', 'host': 'myservices.interoute.com', 'key': 'myusername', 'path': '/myservices', 'api_version': None}
Still i don't know how to pass region in that ,to llist images,when i give location name in list_images it asks for location id and showing error.Any idea guys?

Comment: In this connection establishing its type is in object but when I call listimages() method it showing json parson error as above mentioned in my1st post ,and also when passing location in listimages method ,it gets ask for locationid

Answer (score 1):

A 'region' is not needed for libcloud with CloudStack: See [this link for a working example](http://libcloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/compute/examples.html#create-a-node-on-a-cloudstack-provider-using-a-provided-key-pair-and-security-groups).

From your comments I see that you use interoute.com. By a quick search I found this [tutorial how to work with libcloud on interoute](http://cloudstore.interoute.com/main/knowledge-centre/blog/GettingstartedLibcloud). You can find more examples at [github](https://github.com/Interoute/Libcloud-and-VDC).

Your code seems correct to list all images. But the error message contains `Unknown_ApiKey`, so please check that you provide the valid credentials for you request.

**(Edit)** a working example for CloudStack (interoute.com) is:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

VDCDriver=get_driver(Provider.CLOUDSTACK)

vdc_apikey= 'INSERT YOUR VDC ACCOUNT API KEY HERE'
vdc_secretkey= 'INSERT YOUR VDC ACCOUNT SECRET KEY HERE'
vdc_url= 'https://myservices.interoute.com/myservices/api/vdc'

conn=VDCDriver(key=vdc_apikey, secret=vdc_secretkey, url=vdc_url)

images = conn.list_images()
for i in images:
    print "%s - %s" % (i.extra['displaytext'],i.id)
```

This will output name and id of all available images:

```
openSUSE 13.2 - abcde-1111-abc-1111-abcde
Ubuntu 14.10 - abcde-2222-abc-2222-abcde
Fedora 21 - abcde-3333-abc-333-abcde
```

Comment: Thanks,while creating node showing like this:libcloud.common.types.ProviderError: u'Unable to execute API command deployvirtualmachine due to missing parameter serviceofferingid'
hercode:                                                                                                           node = conn.create_node(name="IRT-CENTOS-6.3", images="my image id", sizes="my size id", ex_security_groups="None",
                   ex_keyname="None")                                                                         Whether need to pass any parameter further for creating a node?

Comment: @user4223185 to create a node you have to pass the objects (not the strings) into `conn.create_node` see [this link for an example](https://github.com/Interoute/Libcloud-and-VDC/blob/master/create_node.py)

Comment: Thanks Andpei, now i ve passed as an object ,but now showing libcloud.common.types.ProviderError: u'The template 2943 is not available for use'
 Whicg=h means image is not available ah?

Comment: In creating a vm,showing template is not available or network id is not available for zone1.Is this related to resource or any ?